# How to get items from a nested array with specific range - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

Updated: Here is the code-sandbox with the live example [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-splice-nested-list-mpgbo). My use case is to build a virtual scroll. I'm able to get it somehow, please suggest better ways or improvements.

I have a nested array of List of classes with a list of students. Something similar to this.

```
"Classes":    
   [
    {
      "ClassId": "XX",
      "ClassTitle": "XX",
      "Students": [
        {
          "StudentId": "XX",
          "StudentName": "XX",
          "Marks": "XX",
          "etc": "XX"
        },
        {
          "StudentId": "XX",
          "StudentName": "XX",
          "Marks": "XX",
          "etc": "XX"
        },
        {
          "StudentId": "XX",
          "StudentName": "XX",
          "Marks": "XX",
          "etc": "XX"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ClassId": "XX",
      "ClassTitle": "XX",
      "Students": [
        {
          "StudentId": "XX",
          "StudentName": "XX",
          "Marks": "XX",
          "etc": "XX"
        },
        {
          "StudentId": "XX",
          "StudentName": "XX",
          "Marks": "XX",
          "etc": "XX"
        },
        {
          "StudentId": "XX",
          "StudentName": "XX",
          "Marks": "XX",
          "etc": "XX"
        },
        {
          "StudentId": "XX",
          "StudentName": "XX",
          "Marks": "XX",
          "etc": "XX"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ClassId": "XX",
      "ClassTitle": "XX",
      "Students": [
        {
          "StudentId": "XX",
          "StudentName": "XX",
          "Marks": "XX",
          "etc": "XX"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ClassId": "XX",
      "ClassTitle": "XX",
      "Students": [
        {
          "StudentId": "XX",
          "StudentName": "XX",
          "Marks": "XX",
          "etc": "XX"
        },
        {
          "StudentId": "XX",
          "StudentName": "XX",
          "Marks": "XX",
          "etc": "XX"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I'm trying to get functionality of splice for the nested list. Flattenning the list will not work for my case as I need the original structure intact.

I tried something like this. Can someone help me with this? Is there a better way to do it simpler.

```
getNestedSplicedData(nestedItems, startIndex, endIndex) {
  console.log("Start and end indexes are:", startIndex, endIndex);
  let visibleItems = [];
  let currentIndex = 0;
  let totalReqItems = endIndex - startIndex + 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < nestedItems.length; i++) {
    let currentItem = nestedItems[i];
    let childItemsLength =
      currentItem[this.childPropertyName] &&
      currentItem[this.childPropertyName].length
        ? currentItem[this.childPropertyName].length
        : 0;
    const nextItemIndex = currentIndex + childItemsLength + 1;

    if (nextItemIndex - 1 < startIndex) {
      // skip previous items
      currentIndex = nextItemIndex;
      // totalReqItems = totalReqItems - (childItemsLength + 1);
    } else if (nextItemIndex < endIndex && startIndex < currentIndex) {
      // currentItem.Name = currentItem.Name + " - " + totalReqItems; // TODO: Remove it
      visibleItems.push(currentItem);
      currentIndex = nextItemIndex;
      totalReqItems = totalReqItems - (childItemsLength + 1);
    } else {
      let currentItemClone = _.cloneDeep(currentItem);
      let st = startIndex - currentIndex -1;
      if (st < 0) {
        st = 0;
      }
      // -1 is for inclussion of root node.
      // another -1 is for the item at start index.
      let ed = st + totalReqItems -1 -1;
      if (ed >= childItemsLength) {
        ed = childItemsLength - 1;
      }
      currentItemClone[this.childPropertyName] = currentItemClone[
        this.childPropertyName
      ].slice(st, ed + 1);
      // currentItemClone.Name = currentItemClone.Name + " - " + totalReqItems; // TODO: Remove it
      visibleItems.push(currentItemClone);
      currentIndex = nextItemIndex;
      totalReqItems = totalReqItems - (ed - st + 1) - 1; // totalReqItems - childLength - parent Item
    }
    if (totalReqItems <= 0) {
      debugger;
      break;
    }
  }

  return visibleItems;
}
}
```

I tried to make the function generic to work for any kind of nested structure of one-level parent-child structure.

Comment: can you please add example of input and output of your function? I don't understand what it's doing

Comment: @Mahesh, can you please further explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I dont understand what "I am trying to get functionality of splice for the nested list" means.  Are you trying to add and remove items from those specific Studen arrays?

Comment: I maybe understand - had problems processing too big JSONs so had to make scripts to split them beforehand. Then made simple iterator IIFE to create double linked list and iterators for simple traversing them also in JS - here https://github.com/eltomjan/ETEhomeTools/blob/master/HTM_HTA/JSON_Iterator_IIFE.js source, examples how to use it are here in some of my older answers here. Maybe you can search its name(?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile, I wrote this implementation. Hope this helps for others as well. Here is the code-sandbox with the live example [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-splice-nested-list-mpgbo)

Any suggestions or improvements or better ways to implement are most welcome.